# find an example of a continuous random variable with pdf that do.not have point of symmetry

Tags: probability, statistics

Find an example of a continuous random variable with probability density function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)$ does not have any points of symmetry but the mean and median of $X$ are still equal.

I am really having hard time to find one example. could anyone help me pls

Comment: Which density functions have you already considered?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A continuous random variable can have a 'piecewise continuous' density function. Perhaps a distribution with something like the following density function will suffice.

[image]

This distribution is a 50:50 mixture of
$\mathsf{Unif}(-2/3, 1)$ and 
$\mathsf{Beta}(1,2).$